# Scala and @Inject annotation

Tags: java, scala, dependency-injection

I know that the best way to deal with dependency injection in Scala is using tools that were built specifically for the language, but I working on a project that must integrate some Scala and Java code.

Then, I am using Google Guice, that implements specification *JSR-330*. Fortunatly, I found no problem during integration of Guice and Scala. I am using *constructor injection*, because I have to deal with immutability.

My question is, why in Scala we have to use the notation `@Inject()` in front of the constructor parameter? Why the `()` paranthesis? It follows an example:

```
class MyClass @Inject() (val another: AnotherClass) {
  // Body of the class
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Otherwise, how could you tell if `(val another: AnotherClass)` is constructor parameter list or arguments to `@Inject`?

Comment: So simple. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

It is all about the syntax of annotating a constructor. Scala requires a constructor annotation to have one (and exactly one) parameter list (even if it is empty)

```
class Bar @Fooable() ( val i : Int) {

}
```

What would the `i` parameter belong to below: The annotation or the `Bar` class?

```
class Bar @Fooable( val i : Int) {

}
```